# C/C++ macro expansions from VS to GCC generates error

Tags: c++, c, gcc, macros

This works in VS C++ but produces an error compiling with GCC:

"error: invalid conversion from 'int ( * )(float, int)' to 'void *' [-fpermissive]|"

```
#define CLASS_HOOK_FUNC(vtable, name, tableindex) oNHook_##name = (_##name)vtable.HookVTableFunctionByIndex(tableindex, hNHook_##name);

#define HOOK_EXPORT(name) CLASS_HOOK_FUNC(g_ctExport, name, EXPORTID_##name);

HOOK_EXPORT(H_Redraw);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft C++ permits an implicit conversion from a function pointer to a `void*` which the standard doesn't permit.  GCC emits an error.

There was a recent bug report on Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/786150/msvc-performs-implicit-conversion-of-function-pointers-to-void

You just need to place an explicit cast to `void*` on which ever argument to `HookVTableFunctionByIndex()` is taking the function pointer as a `void*`.

Answer (score 0):

MSC allows implicit conversion from function pointer to void *. But this is not valid on every compiler. So even though this is valid on gcc, it is not allowed unless you force gcc to allow it by adding -fpermissive